# What is the lifetime of a default argument temporary bound to a reference parameter?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, lifetime, temporary-objects

I thought references only extend the lifetime of temporaries to the lifetime of the reference itself, but the output of the following snippet seems contradictory:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X{ ~X(){ std::cout << "Goodbye, cruel world!\n"; } };

X const& f(X const& x = X()){
  std::cout << "Inside f()\n";
  return x;
}

void g(X const& x){
  std::cout << "Inside g()\n";
}

int main(){
  g(f());
}
```

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/9d23d2b39382ce671217c3707d9349aa) Output:

```
Inside f()
Inside g()
Goodbye, cruel world!
```

So it seems the temporary is destroyed after `g()` is called... what gives?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The standard handles this in a special case in `§12.2 [class.temporary]`:

> p4 There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression. [...]
>
> p5 The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except:
>
> - A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) **persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call**.

The standard also has a handy note on full-expressions and the evaluation of their subexpressions with regards to default parameters in `§1.9 [intro.execution] p11`:

> [ *Note:* The evaluation of a full-expression can include the evaluation of subexpressions that are not lexically part of the full-expression. For example, subexpressions involved in evaluating **default arguments (8.3.6) are considered to be created in the expression that calls the function**, not the expression that defines the default argument. *—end note* ]

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, +1. (I do not mean to compete with your nice self answer here). Just a side note for anyone interested. If you want a similar effect but allowing non-const you could use move semantics:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X{
   ~X(){ std::cout << "Goodbye, cruel world!\n"; }
   X(X && x){  std::cout << "moved "; }
   X(){}
};

X  f(X x = X()){
  std::cout << "Inside f()\n";
  return x;
}

void g(X x){
  std::cout << "Inside g()\n";
}

int main(){
   g(f());
}
```

gives

```
Inside f()
moved Inside g()
Goodbye, cruel world!
Goodbye, cruel world!
```

Comment: You can also just use `X&&` and return `std::move(x)`. :)

Comment: @Xeo "return std::move(x)" should be avoided in this case, see more details eg at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856344/when-should-stdmove-be-used-on-a-function-return-value

Answer (score 0):

> So it seems the temporary is destroyed after g() is called.

That's true because the lifetime of the temporary starts once f() is called and ends once g() is exited. That's because:

> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the **full-expression** containing the call.

The *full-expression* here is `g(f())` not `f()` because your f() function is actually looks like this

```
void g(X const& x){
  std::cout << "Inside g()\n";
}

X const& f(X const& x){
  std::cout << "Inside f()\n";
  return x;
}

g(f( X() ));
```