# When should std::move be used on a function return value?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

In this case

```
struct Foo {};
Foo meh() {
  return std::move(Foo());
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the move is unnecessary, because the newly created `Foo` will be an xvalue.

But what in cases like these?

```
struct Foo {};
Foo meh() {
  Foo foo;
  //do something, but knowing that foo can safely be disposed of
  //but does the compiler necessarily know it?
  //we may have references/pointers to foo. how could the compiler know?
  return std::move(foo); //so here the move is needed, right?
}
```

There the move is needed, I suppose?

Comment: When you are using Visual Studio.

Comment: Just FYI in the second case, you *cannot* have any usable references/pointers to foo anymore when you return from the function.

Comment: What are you doing with the returned value? `Foo f = meh();` worked with (N)RVO already in C++98.

Comment: I wonder if explicitly calling std::move will prevent NRVO...

Comment: @thang it depends: it prevents NRVO if the constructor has side-effects; it does not prevent NRVO otherwise (as-if rule). Whether the compiler will still do NRVO is a different question, and needs an answer to "which compiler?" first.

Comment: but it's more than just the constructor?  it would be a little presumptive of the compiler to assume the meaning of std::move, I think, so that it can just completely elide away the entire line std::move(foo)?

Comment: @thang: `std::move` is a function template, so the compiler doesn't have to assume the meaning. It can inspect the definition. As it happens, though, compilers can also assume the meanings of standard functions if they want to.

Comment: `std::move` is an identity operation. It never actually does anything. It's just a marker for rvalues. If the compiler has the move constructor of `Foo` on hand it can see if it has observable effects and decide upon that. If it has no observable effects, how can you tell the difference?

Comment: I can't believe it's not a duplicate. If it really isn't, then +1 for posting a reference question for future duplicates (which I'm sure will arise).

Comment: "We may have references/pointers to foo" - if you do, you're not allowed to use them after the `return` statement, regardless of `std::move`!

Comment: `Foo()` is a prvalue, not an xvalue

Answer (score 173, accepted):

In the case of `return std::move(foo);` the `move` is superfluous because of 12.8/32:

> When the criteria for elision of a copy operation are met or would be
>   met save for the fact that the source object is a function parameter,
>   and the object to be copied is designated by an lvalue, overload
>   resolution to select the constructor for the copy is ﬁrst performed as
>   if the object were designated by an rvalue.

`return foo;` is a case of NRVO, so copy elision is permitted. `foo` is an lvalue. So the constructor selected for the "copy" from `foo` to the return value of `meh` is required to be the move constructor if one exists.

Adding `move` does have a potential effect, though: it prevents the move being elided, because `return std::move(foo);` is *not* eligible for NRVO.

As far as I know, 12.8/32 lays out the *only* conditions under which a copy from an lvalue can be replaced by a move. The compiler is not permitted in general to detect that an lvalue is unused after the copy (using DFA, say), and make the change on its own initiative. I'm assuming here that there's an observable difference between the two -- if the observable behavior is the same then the "as-if" rule applies.

So, to answer the question in the title, use `std::move` on a return value when you want it to be moved and it would not get moved anyway. That is:

- you want it to be moved, and
- it is an lvalue, and
- it is not eligible for copy elision, and
- it is not the name of a by-value function parameter.

Considering that this is quite fiddly and moves are *usually* cheap, you might like to say that in non-template code you can simplify this a bit. Use `std::move` when:

- you want it to be moved, and
- it is an lvalue, and
- you can't be bothered worrying about it.

By following the simplified rules you sacrifice some move elision. For types like `std::vector` that are cheap to move you'll probably never notice (and if you do notice you can optimize). For types like `std::array` that are expensive to move, or for templates where you have no idea whether moves are cheap or not, you're more likely to be bothered worrying about it.

Comment: C++: bone simple. Clearly.

Comment: C++: if you don't laugh, you'll cry.

Comment: What about trying to return variables declared as `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` when function is declared to return `std::unique_ptr<Base>`? In gcc and mingw-w64 it just works, but vanilla mingw (based gcc 4.9.3, targeting `i686-pc-cygwin`) needs `std::move(x)` to compile.

Comment: @rr: not sure. I'd expect to need the `std::move` in that case (because the types don't match and so copy elision is off the table), but I could be overlooking something. The fact it differs between 32-bit and 64-bit mingw is odd. I can't off-hand think of a reason why the compiler or platform authors would intend that.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Just to make things straight, mingw-w64 is not just a 64-bit version of mingw - it's a fork that introduces some substantial updates.

Comment: What if one wants to retain move elision but forbid copy-construction without deleting (or making private) the copy constructor of the class?

Answer (score 52):

The move is unnecessary in both cases. In the second case, `std::move` is superfluous because you are returning a local variable by value, and the compiler will understand that since you're not going to use that local variable anymore, it can be moved from rather than being copied.

Comment: Use of `std::move` considered harmful, can prevent elision

Comment: Correction: Use of std::move *for return values* considered harmful, can prevent elision

Answer (score 35):

On a return value, if the return expression refers directly to the name of a local lvalue (i.e. at this point an xvalue) there is no need for the `std::move`. On the other hand, if the return expression is **not** the identifier, it will not be moved automatically, so for example, you would need the explicit `std::move` in this case:

```
T foo(bool which) {
   T a = ..., b = ...;
   return std::move(which? a : b);
   // alternatively: return which? std::move(a), std::move(b);
}
```

When returning a named local variable or a temporary expression directly, you should avoid the explicit `std::move`. The compiler *must* (and will in the future) move automatically in those cases, and adding `std::move` might affect other optimizations.

Comment: It should be noted, if one of the params of the ternary is created in-place, it will be constructed into the return variable directly. However a move on it will prevent this. This makes the second alternative more flexible - one will only move the named arg.

Answer (score 33):

There are lots of answers about when it shouldn't be moved, but the question is "when should it be moved?"

Here is a contrived example of when it should be used:

```
std::vector<int> append(std::vector<int>&& v, int x) {
  v.push_back(x);
  return std::move(v);
}
```

ie, when you have a function that takes an rvalue reference, modifies it, and then returns a copy of it.  (In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) behavior here changes)  Now, in practice, this design is almost always better:

```
std::vector<int> append(std::vector<int> v, int x) {
  v.push_back(x);
  return v;
}
```

which also allows you to take non-rvalue parameters.

Basically, if you have an rvalue reference within a function that you want to return by moving, you have to call `std::move`.  If you have a local variable (be it a parameter or not), returning it implicitly `move`s (and this implicit move can be elided away, while an explicit move cannot).  If you have a function or operation that takes local variables, and returns a reference to said local variable, you have to `std::move` to get move to occur (as an example, the trinary `?:` operator).

Comment: There is no benefit to using `std::move` on an `int` ; maybe this would be a better example if `x` was a class type with an expensive copy (e.g. appending to a string)

Comment: @M.M Improvement accepted

Comment: std::vector<int> append(std::vector<int>&& v, int x) {
  v.push_back(x);
  return std::move(v);
}

v in this case can be lvalue reference, wouldn't it put what is referenced by v into "undefined state" ?

Comment: @hombre `std::move` is just an rvalue cast.  `v` is clearly an rvalue reference, not an lvalue reference; no perfect forwarding can occur here.  `v` is also an lvalue at point of use, so the cast to rvalue reference is needed to ensure this function chains properly.  I suspect you have the usual confusion that you think `std::move` moves things.

Comment: I double checked. append(std::vector<int>&& v ... ) can only accept an rvalue as v. A caller would be forced to use std::move to call this api. Wouldn't RVO optimize v copy away on the return?

Comment: figured out the lvalue part playing with std::unique_ptr

Answer (score 3):

A C++ compiler is free to use `std::move(foo)`:

- if it is known that `foo` is at the end of its lifetime, and
- the implicit use of `std::move` won't have any effect on the semantics of the C++ code other than the semantic effects allowed by the C++ specification.

It depends on the optimization capabilities of the C++ compiler whether it is able to compute which transformations from `f(foo); foo.~Foo();` to `f(std::move(foo)); foo.~Foo();` are profitable in terms of performance or in terms of memory consumption, while adhering to the C++ specification rules.

---

**Conceptually** speaking, year-2017 C++ compilers, such as GCC 6.3.0, are **able to optimize** this code:

```
Foo meh() {
    Foo foo(args);
    foo.method(xyz);
    bar();
    return foo;
}
```

into this code:

```
void meh(Foo *retval) {
   new (retval) Foo(arg);
   retval->method(xyz);
   bar();
}
```

which avoids calling the copy-constructor and the destructor of `Foo`.

---

Year-2017 C++ compilers, such as GCC 6.3.0, are **unable to optimize** these codes:

```
Foo meh_value() {
    Foo foo(args);
    Foo retval(foo);
    return retval;
}

Foo meh_pointer() {
    Foo *foo = get_foo();
    Foo retval(*foo);
    delete foo;
    return retval;
}
```

into these codes:

```
Foo meh_value() {
    Foo foo(args);
    Foo retval(std::move(foo));
    return retval;
}

Foo meh_pointer() {
    Foo *foo = get_foo();
    Foo retval(std::move(*foo));
    delete foo;
    return retval;
}
```

which means that a year-2017 programmer needs to specify such optimizations explicitly.

Comment: @M.M I don't care about C++ terminology in this instance that much. The expression "call to std::move" in the answer has meaning equivalent to "use of std::move".

Comment: @M.M Do you have further suggestion on how to improve the answer?

Comment: @atomsymbol this is a great informational answer, that adds to the existing ones, I don't know what the fuss is about.

Answer (score -9):

`std::move` is totally unnecessary when returning from a function, and really gets into the realm of you -- the programmer -- trying to babysit things that you should leave to the compiler.

What happens when you `std::move` something out of a function that isn't a variable local to that function?  You can say that you'll never write code like that, but what happens if you write code that's just fine, and then refactor it and absent-mindedly don't change the `std::move`.  You'll have fun tracking that bug down.

The compiler, on the other hand, is mostly incapable of making these kinds of mistakes.

Also: Important to note that returning a local variable from a function does **not** necessarily create an rvalue or use move semantics.

[See here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Comment: The note in the final paragraph is wrong. The compiler is required to treat it as an rvalue.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes and no, it will be treated as an rvalue but my compiler prefers elision to move construction and hence it's kind of true to say that there'll be no move semantics (because the move constructor won't be called at all)

Comment: The first paragraph is wrong.  It is almost always true that returning `std::move` is a bad idea, but there exist cases where returning `std::move` is the right thing to do.