# C++ lifespan of factory returned smart pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers, rvalue-reference

I am using a factory pattern in C++11 which is in the scope of my **main()** function and is invoked like this:

```
histogram_requests -> AddNewPostfix( Postfix_factory :: get_postfix( "Layers", ntuple_reader ) );
```

The **Postfix_factory::get_postfix()** is a static member function returning an **std :: unique_ptr< Postfix>**. An example return value is:

```
return std :: move( std :: unique_ptr<Postfix>( new Layers_postfix( ntuple_reader_p ) ));
```

My first question is if this is actually valid to do? Is the returned pointer destroyed in the end of my **main()** scope?

The second thing is that I want to pass this pointer to a function. What is the correct way of doing it? My program compiles when I set the argument type of **AddNewPostFix()** to either an **std::unique_ptr** or an **std::unique_ptr&&** but fails as a simple reference. I do not want to let my **AddNewPostFix()** to accidently delete the data in my pointer, but I not sure that either of these is safe. Can anyone tell me how to do this correctly and safely?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> return std :: move( std :: unique_ptr<Postfix>( new Layers_postfix( ntuple_reader_p ) ));
> ```

Two things are noteworthy here:

1. [You don't need `std::move` in your `return` statement.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856344/when-should-stdmove-be-used-on-a-function-return-value)
2. You should use [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). It's officially supported only since C++14, but either your compiler supports it anyway or you can easily create your own version of it.

> Is the returned pointer destroyed in the end of my `main()` scope?

"The returned pointer" can refer to several things.

The `std::unique_ptr` object is destroyed, of course. All local objects are destroyed when their scope ends. The raw-pointer data member inside of the `std::unique_ptr` is also destroyed, but that's trivial.

I think what you really mean is the object which is pointed to and which is managed by the `std::unique_ptr`, i.e. the dynamically allocated `Postfix`. That object will also be destroyed, yes, because the `std::unique_ptr` is not moved to anywhere when your `main` ends.

If `Postfix` would not be destroyed, then you'd have a memory leak and `std::unique_ptr` would be pretty much useless, wouldn't it?

> The second thing is that I want to pass this pointer to a function. What is the correct way of doing it?

This question is way too broad. Herb Sutter once wrote [an entire article about passing smart pointers to functions](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/). It's a very long article, with interesting user comments, too. You should definitely read it. Here are Sutter's guidelines:

---

> Don’t pass a smart pointer as a function parameter unless you want to
>   use or manipulate the smart pointer itself, such as to share or
>   transfer ownership.

---

> Prefer passing objects by value, *, or &, not by smart pointer.

---

> Express a “sink” function using a by-value `unique_ptr` parameter.

---

> Use a non-const `unique_ptr&` parameter only to modify the `unique_ptr`.

---

> Don’t use a `const unique_ptr&` as a parameter; use `widget*` instead

---

> Express that a function will store and share ownership of a heap object using a by-value `shared_ptr` parameter.

---

> Use a non-const `shared_ptr&` parameter only to modify the `shared_ptr`. Use a `const shared_ptr&` as a parameter only if you’re not sure whether or not you’ll take a copy and share ownership; otherwise use `widget*` instead (or if not nullable, a `widget&`).

---

> I do not want to let my `AddNewPostFix()` to accidently delete the data in my pointer, but I not sure that either of these is safe.

The safest thing would be not to pass a pointer but a `Postfix&` or a `Postfix const&`. Of course, people could still try `delete &postfix` or employ similar bad practices. But as the saying goes, C++ protects against Murphy, not against Machiavelli.

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Postfix
{
    std::string layers;
    int ntuple_reader;

    Postfix(std::string const& layers, int ntuple_reader) :
        layers(layers),
        ntuple_reader(ntuple_reader)
    {
    }

    ~Postfix()
    {
        std::cout << "dtr\n";
    }
};

std::unique_ptr<Postfix> get_postfix(std::string const& layers, int ntuple_reader)
{
    return std::make_unique<Postfix>(layers, ntuple_reader);
}

void AddNewPostfix(Postfix const& postfix)
{
    std::cout << "AddNewPostfix\n";
    // do something with postfix.layers and postfix.ntuple_reader
}

int main()
{
    int ntuple_reader = 123;
    auto postfix_ptr = get_postfix("Layers", ntuple_reader);
    AddNewPostfix(*postfix_ptr);
}
```

As you can see in the output, the destructor of `Postfix` is correctly called at the end of `main`.

Comment: **0. )** I don't have c++14 support, so I cannot afford using **make_unique()**
**1. )** I don't really get why I shouldn't move the unique_ptr. Shouldn't it be deleted in the end of my factory function without moving (and converting it into an rvalue)?
**2. )** About the main question (the lifespan of my unique_ptr), I was actually curious if it lives until the end of the main (not if it is deleted there or not), but from your answer I deduced that it is physically present in my **main()**, so **you have answered my question.**
**3. )** **Thank you for the example!**

Comment: @AdamHunyadi: 0) `make_unique` is easy to write yourself. 1) For a class with a move constructor, returning implies moving. 2) Not sure what you mean... `main` is not different from other functions with regards to this. 3) You are welcome :)

Comment: You gave me a good idea to write a debug prompt as the destructor is called. Unfortunately my destructor is called right after my AddNewPostfix() call. Which is not correct.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi: I am not sure what the real problem is. Have you considered that `std::unique_ptr` might be the wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score -1):

Returning a smart pointer is fine until you decide that it needs to be held in a different type of smart pointer. I'd just return a raw pointer and let the caller decide what it wants to do with it. In your case, std::move is unnecessary.

To pass it to a function, make the function parameter a const T& and use the dereference operator on the smart pointer.

```
void someFunction(const T& t)
{
}

std::unique_ptr<T> t = ...;
SomeFunction(*t);
```

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused. Wouldn't the data held in my unique pointer get deleted (for having an instance of unique_ptr getting out of scope after returning from the function) without an **std::move()**?

Comment: @AdamHunyadi: Yes, it would be deleted. That's the whole point of it. But by the time that happens, `someFunction` has already done its job, so there's no problem, unless `someFunction` decides to store a pointer to the referenced `T` somewhere else, which would be quite evil (`global_pointer = &t`).