# How to move non-copyable local variable out of lambda in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, move-semantics

I want to implement a simple runtime check macro, so it works like:

```
CHECK(expr) << "Some problem!";
```

I wrote a simplified logging class to do so:

```
class Log {
 public:
  Log() = default;
  Log(const Log&) = delete;

  ~Log() {
    cout << this << " dtor" << endl;
    cout << stream_.str() << endl;
  }

  template <class T>
  Log& operator<<(const T& info) {
    cout << this << " <<" << endl;
    stream_ << info;
    return *this;
  }

 private:
  stringstream stream_;
};
```

And let the macro be:

```
#define CHECK(expr) \
  if (!(expr)) [] { /* See attempts below */ }()
```

Now let's try to implement the lambda.

---

#### Attempt #1

The simplest way should be:

```
[] {
  Log log;
  log << "A";
  return log;
}
```

But [no luck](https://ideone.com/UxJSgS) - the copy constructor is deleted:

```
error: use of deleted function 'Log::Log(const Log&)'
```

#### Attempt #2

Ok, let's move the local variable explicitly:

```
[] {
  Log log;
  log << "A";
  return move(log);
}
```

Hmm, still [no luck](https://ideone.com/gt1cpo).

#### Attempt #3

A desperate attempt that certainly shouldn't work:

```
[]() -> Log&& {
  Log log;
  log << "A";
  return move(log);
}
```

It compiles and even [runs](https://ideone.com/kWU3Kh), but the `operator <<` is called after destructor:

```
0xbfe84064 dtor
A
0xbfe84064 <<
```

---

Help me to figure out what am I doing wrong with returning a variable from lambda?

Comment: I'd really avoid return local variable from function (including lambda expression). In your case - just `#define CHECK(e) if (!(e)) Log{} << "A"`. Even better for some other reason `#define CHECK(e) if (e) {} else Log{} << "A"`

Comment: @PiotrNycz It's not a good variant for me, since I want to print a stack trace along with a user-provided message - that's why I use `Log` inside lambda to do some stuff.

Comment: Not a problem at all. You can create object that prints stack track - like `Log{} << stackTracePrinter`.  Or you can do everything you can imagine in some Log specialization constructor...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the move constructor `default`, i.e.

```
Log(Log&&) = default;
```

because otherwise the existence of a user-provided copy ctor (even if `delete`d) [disables the move ctor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-declared_move_constructor). You should also `return log;` instead of `return move(log);`, as the default move ctor will be invoked (since the copy ctor is deleted). See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856344/when-should-stdmove-be-used-on-a-function-return-value) for more details on why `return move` should in general be avoided.

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ef04cfcdfc7b36c)