# std::move changes address of variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I found unexpected (at least for me) behavior.

```
class A
{
    char  _text[100];
    char* _beg;
    char* _end;
public:
    explicit A(char* text, size_t tsize) : _beg(&text[0]), _end(&text[std::min(tsize, 99)]) 
    {
        memcpy(_text, text, std::min(tsize, 99));
        *_end = '\0';
    }
    inline std::string get_text()
    {
        return std::move(std::string(_beg, _end));  
    }
};
```

After that somewhere in code I do that:

```
  A* add_A(A&& a)
  {
     list_a.push_back(std::move(a));
     return &(list_a.back());
  }

  std::list<A> list_a;
  {
      add_A(A("my_text", 7));
      list_a.back().get_text(); //returns "my_text"
  }
  list_a.back().get_text(); //returns trash
```

As only I move this class (using `std::move`), and call `get_text()` of object that was moved, I get trash, as if after movement address of variable `_text` changed, and so `_beg` and `_end` points to nowhere.

Does address of variables really can be changes after `std::move` (I thought `move` don't really move object, it was invented for that)?

If it can be changed, what is usual pattern to handle it (to change pointers accordingly)?

If it can't be change, may that behavior happens because I try to move such object to `std::list` (and so there somehow happens copying, it changes address of variables and makes pointers point to wrong positions)?

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with `std::move`. It will have the same problem even if you won't use it.

Comment: `_end = '\0';` Did you mean `*_end`?

Comment: @Michael, yes, you're right, mistake happens when I copy code here

Comment: @Rakete1111: The problem is plainly visible in the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856344/when-should-stdmove-be-used-on-a-function-return-value

Comment: @Arkady: Don't retype code. Use copy-pasting to paste the literal, actual code that you're using at home as your minimal example. If that's too much code, rework the minimal example to make it minimaler.

Comment: What's the purpose of storing the string in a raw buffer in the first place? This is C++... there is no reason to not just store an `std::string`.

Comment: @qxz: There are *plenty* of reasons to use such a type instead of `std::string`. The most important being memory allocation. Granted, that would be a type for special-cased needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::move` has no moving parts, it simply promotes the input parameter to an rvalue reference -- remember that inside the body of `foo(T&& t) { ... }` the use of `t` by name evaluates as an lvalue (reference to rvalue).

```
inline std::string get_text()
{
    return std::move(std::string(_beg, _end));
}
```

Breaking this down:

```
std::string(_beg, _end);
```

creates an anonymous, temporary std::string object constructed from `_beg` to `_end`. This is an rvalue.

```
std::move(...);
```

forcibly promotes this to an rvalue reference and prevents the compiler from performing return-value optimization. What you want is

```
return std::string(_beg, _end);
```

See [assembly code comparison](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXATuA5gPgChDMsYIMkBlJAb0KSUzgC4XS8mBGACgEoGdQYywIMMLGCYZWLALYB7AG4IezNhzC5%2BfANyCAvoMHr22TmgBM/QfUYixEqac3a9hwgf0kZG81qRcNG8lBRA4bh4qADImATtAtCQAXiYAOjRedyMSEAAvBAB9Siso2LR4wSCU9NLsoAA%3D%3D)),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

You probably also want to use

```
list_a.emplace_back(std::move(a));
```

Unfortunately, there are two flaws in this approach.

The simpler is that the term `moving` can be a bit misleading, it sounds very one way. But in practice it is often a two way swap: the two objects exchange properties so that when the temporary object goes out of scope it performs cleanup of whatever the other object previously owned:

```
struct S {
    char* s_;
    S(const char* s) : s_(strdup(s)) {}
    ~S() { release(); }
    void release() { if (s_) free(s_); }
    S(const S& s) : s_(strdup(s.s_)) {}
    S(S&& s) : s_(s.s_) { s.s_ = nullptr; }
    S& operator=(const S& s) { release(); s_ = strdup(s); return *this; }
    S& operator=(S&& s) { std::swap(s_, s.s_); return *this; }
};
```

Note this line:

```
    S& operator=(S&& s) { std::swap(s_, s.s_); return *this; }
```

When we write:

```
S s1("hello");
s1 = S("world");
```

the second line invokes the move-assignment operator. The pointer for the copy of `hello` is moved into the temporary, the temporary goes out of scope and is destroyed, the copy of "hello" is freed.

Doing this swap with your array of characters is significantly less efficient than a one-way copy would be:

```
struct S {
    char s_[100];
    S(const S& s) {
        std::copy(std::begin(s.s_), std::end(s.s_), std::begin(s_));
    }
    S(S&& s) {
        char t_[100];
        std::copy(std::begin(s.s_), std::end(s.s_), std::begin(t_));
        std::copy(std::begin(s_), std::end(s_), std::begin(s.s_));
        std::copy(std::begin(t_), std::end(t_), std::end(s_));
    }
};
```

You don't *have* to do this, the rvalue parameter only needs to be in a safe to destroy state, but the above is what the *default* move operators are going to do.

The disasterous part of your code is that the default move operator is naive.

```
struct S {
    char text_[100];
    char *beg_, *end_;
    S() : beg_(text_), end_(text_ + 100) {}
};
```

Consider the following copy-construction:

```
S s(S());
```

What does `s.beg_` point to?

Answer: it points to `S().text_`, not `s.text_`. You would need to write a copy constructor that copied the contents of `text_` and then pointed its own `beg_` and `end_` to its own `text_` rather than copying the source values.

The same problem occurs with the move operator: it will *move* the contents of `text_` but it will also *move* the pointers, and have no clue that they are relative.

You'll either need to write copy/move constructors and assignment operators, or you could consider replacing `beg_` and `end_` with a single `size_t` size value.

But in either case, move is not your friend here: you're not transferring ownership or performing a shallow copy, all of your data is inside your object.

Answer (score 4):

Moving in C++ is just a specialized form of copy, where you modify the data in the object being moved from. That's how `unique_ptr` works; you copy the pointer from one `unique_ptr` object to the other, then set the original value to NULL.

When you move an object, you are creating a *new object*, one who gets its data from another object. The address of members don't "change"; it's simply *not the same object*.

Because you didn't write a copy/move constructor, that means the compiler will write one for you. And all they do is copy each element. So the newly moved-to object will have pointers that point *to the old object*.

An object that is about to be destroyed.

It's like moving into a house that happens to look identical to your old one. No matter how much it looks like your old house, it isn't. You still have to change your address, since it's a new house. So too must the addresses of `_beg` and `_end` be updated.

Now, you could create a move constructor/assignment operator (along with a copy constructor/assignment operator) to update your pointers. But quite frankly, that's just wallpapering over *bad design*. It's not a good idea to have pointers to subobjects within the same object if you can help it. Instead of begin/end pointers, just have an actual *size*:

```
class A
{
    char  _text[100];
    size_t _size;
public:
    explicit A(char* text, size_t tsize) : _size(tsize)
    {
        strncpy(_text, text, 100);
    }
    inline std::string get_text()
    {
        return std::string(_text, _size); //Explicit `move` call is unnecessary
    }
};
```

This way, there is no need to store begin/end pointers. Those can be synthesized as needed.

Comment: But why does it return trash on the second call? As far as I know the member variables didn't change.

Comment: `_end` and `_beg` still point into the original object, which has been deallocated.

Comment: I find this answer uses the concept of a "new object" as if one should only be allowed to think at the object abstraction level, and not about what happens to where and how those objects reside in memory (the latter is much more interesting to low level programmers.) As such, not that helpful of an answer.

Comment: @ldog: "*not about what happens to where and how those objects reside in memory*" Um, that *is* how it "resides in memory". As far as the memory is concerned, you're creating a new object. What I described is the low-level details. It's only at the higher level abstraction where you start saying that there is only one object that has been "moved" around. At the low level, there are two objects.