# Is copy/move elision allowed when returning *&object?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo {
    Foo() { }
    Foo(const Foo &) { printf("copy\n"); }
    Foo(Foo &&) { printf("move\n"); }
};

Foo getFoo() {
    Foo f;
    return *&f;
}

int main() {
    getFoo();
}
```

C++14 Standard says (12.8/31) that copy/move elision allowed:

> in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the
>   expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than
>   a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv- unqualiﬁed
>   type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be
>   omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the
>   function’s return value

In my example, return expression is not a name, so I don't think elision is allowed.

I've checked GCC/clang/MSVC, and while clang/MSVC doesn't elide copy, GCC does. Does GCC violate the standard here?

Comment: Well I don't see why a compiler would keep the redundant `*` and `&` operators. Also, which version of the compilers are you using? Are you building in C++14 mode on all? Also, when quoting the standard, please indicate where the code is from (name or chapter/section numbers).

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, why are you using `printf` for output? Why not `std::cout`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - The compiler probably doesn't keep them in the emitted code. But they do affect the semantics of the expression for the standards point of view. This simply isn't an id-expression (or a name).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I've added chapter/section numbers, thanks for the suggestion. I've checked ~10 different compilers, all of them did the same, so I don't think version numbers are necessary. I used `printf` because I'm used to it, I've never used `std::cout` (actually, I've written an own implementation for printing, which combines (IMHO) good properties of `printf` and `cout`: it's printf style, but can print anything type-safely)

Comment: Shortly after the section you quoted, the standard says: _when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move_ This rule, combined with the one you quoted, allows the copy elision of `return *&f;`.

Comment: @pschill: `f` in `getFoo` is not a temporary object.

Comment: @geza Yes, but `*&f` is.

Comment: `*&f` is a `Foo&`, which isn't a temporary class object.

The paragraph quoted by @pschill was removed in C++17 as part of the ["simplified value categories"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html) changes.

Under these changes, `return` needs to materialise a temporary `Foo`, which is clearly copy-elidable. However, the copy-construction from `f` isn't so clear to me here.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the "as-if" rule doesn't apply here, because your copy and move constructors have side effects (they perform IO).  Thus GCC can't be eliding the copy/move under that heading.

At a quick glance, I can't see any other wording that would permit elision, so I think it is a bug in GCC.  On the other hand, I would quite like the standard to widen the scope of copy/move elision to include this case.  (In the minimal example you have presented, I can't see how it would cause problems - I presume you have a large example where it does.)

Comment: Compilers are allowed to elide copy/move even if they have side effects in this case.

Comment: @Zereges When copy/move elision is allowed, it is allowed even if the compilers have *side effects* (in the formal sense defined by the standard).  The point of my first paragraph is that if the constructors don't have side effects, they can be elided even if elision is *not* allowed under 12.8/31 (under the "as-if" rule).  12.8/31 doesn't apply "in this case", "as-if" doesn't apply "in this case" => The elision is a bug.

Comment: @Zereges Do I need to expand my answer to include some of the above comment?