# Why is move assignment not called?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Item
{
  Item () {cout << "Item constructor called." << endl;}
  ~Item () {cout << "Item destructor called." << endl;}
  Item (const Item& item): x(item.x) {cout << "Item copy constructor called." << endl;}
  Item (Item&& item) : x(std::move(item.x)) {cout << "Item move constructor called." << endl;}
  Item& operator=(const Item& item) { x= item.x; cout << "Item assignment operator called." << endl; return *this;}
  Item& operator=(Item&& item) { x= std::move(item.x); cout << "Item move assignment operator called." << endl; return *this;}

  int x = 0;
};

struct ItemHandler
{
    Item getItem() 
    {
      cout << "getItem called."<< endl; 
      return item;
    }

    Item item{}; 
};

int main()
{
  ItemHandler ih;  
  cout << "trying move assignment" << endl;
  Item&& it = ih.getItem();
}
```

I was expecting that since ih.getItem() will create a copy then move assign it to it. But Here is the output that I got:

```
Item constructor called.
trying move assignment
getItem called.
Item copy constructor called.
Item destructor called.
Item destructor called.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Item getItem() 
{
    return item;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
Item getItem() 
{
    return this->item;
}
```

`this->item` is a data member lvalue. The compiler will not move it for you unless you are explicit about it. Lvalues are implicitly moved only [for some special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14856553/598696).

---

The correct way to solve this problem is to provide ref-qualified versions of `getItem()`:

```
Item& getItem() &   
{
    return this->item;
}

const Item& getItem() const&
{
    return this->item;
}

Item getItem() &&
{
    return std::move(this->item);
}
```

And then use `std::move` in your main:

```
int main()
{
    ItemHandler ih;  
    Item it = std::move(ih).getItem();
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't `Item &&it = ih.getItem()` call the `&&` version of `getItem` ?

Comment: @Tobias: because `ih` is an lvalue. The type of `it` doesn't matter at all here, only the type of `ih` does.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo as I understand, even if this->item is an lvalue getItem() creates a temporary copy of that lvalue before returning. Which means it is an rvalue right?

Comment: @jko: correct - the returned temporary is an rvalue. The temporary however is construct from `this->item`, which is an lvalue. The copy constructor is invoked instead of the move constructor.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I think I understand that part but after returning the rvalue from ih.getItem(), I am confused with why doesn't `Item&&` `it` `=` call the move assignment operator?

Comment: @jko: because `Item&&` is not an object, it is a reference. You are not constructing/assigning to anything

Comment: i see. so that means after returning rvalue, it is already referenced by &&it?