# Is there any benefit or downside using std::move with Rcpp data structures?

Tags: r, c++11, move, rcpp

In the [comment](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/122#issuecomment-36420487), it is said that move semantics are not adopted in Rcpp classes. Some developers prefer writing `return std::move(x)` in all functions when C++11 is enabled just as the following:

```
NumericVector test(const NumericVector& x) {
  NumericVector y(x.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    y[i] = x[i] * 2;
  }
  return std::move(y);
}
```

I'm wondering if there's any benefit or downside writing Rcpp code like this, or any risk that code runs into trouble if the code is more complex?

Comment: Why not do it a few millions times with vectors of different sizes in a quick benchmark?  It could be faster; it could be that the C interface we have to use gets in the way and it is both the same (or slower).  Could also depend on the compiler, version and OS.

Comment: A series of benchmark with different data size shows very little difference in performance. I'm wondering if there may be any downside about this?

Comment: Might be a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14856553/1794345

Comment: Spot on, thanks for the link.  Could consider it a duplicate, could keep it for the Rcpp crowd.