# How to return && object from function?

Tags: c++, return-value, rvalue-reference

I have `TTempTable` class with move symantics. I wrote

```
TTempTable&& MyFunction() {
   TTempTable tmp = f(...);
   ...
   return std::move(tmp);
}
```

and got no compiler errors.

Was this correct?

Comment: Have a look at [this rule in the C++ Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f45-dont-return-a-t)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it is not correct.

You're [returning a reference to a local variable](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f45-dont-return-a-t). That reference is dangling.

Like any dangling thing, the compiler won't [always] diagnose it for you.

Return by value, and remove the `std::move` ([it's redundant and inhibits elision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14856344/560648)).