# C++ no matching constructor initialization of []

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a function like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

#define GRADIENT_THRESHOLD 200.0
#define ANGLE_RANGE 20

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class Circle {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int r;

    Circle(int x, int y, int r) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->r = r;
    }

    double area() {
        return PI * pow(r, 2);
    }
};



Vector <Circle> collect_circles_from_houghSpace(Mat &houghSpaceCircle, double voting_threshold) {
    int height = houghSpaceCircle.size[0];
    int width = houghSpaceCircle.size[1];
    int radius = houghSpaceCircle.size[2];
    std::vector <Circle> circles;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int r = 0; r < radius; r++) {
                if (houghSpaceCircle.at<cv::Vec3i>(y, x)[r] > voting_threshold) {
                    circles.push_back(Circle(x, y, r));

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return circles;
}
```

When I compile it, I get an error saying:
In file included from sobel.cpp:2:

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/opencv@2/2.4.13.7_5/include/opencv/cv.h:64:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/opencv@2/2.4.13.7_5/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4932:
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv@2/2.4.13.7_5/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:2415:23: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Circle []'
        newData = new _Tp[newCapacity];
                      ^
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv@2/2.4.13.7_5/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:2400:13: note: in instantiation of member function 'cv::Vector<Circle>::reserve' requested here
            reserve(_size);
            ^
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv@2/2.4.13.7_5/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:2305:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'cv::Vector<Circle>::set' requested here
    { set(!vec.empty() ? (_Tp*)&vec[0] : 0, vec.size(), _copyData); }
      ^
sobel.cpp:166:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'cv::Vector<Circle>::Vector' requested here
    return circles;
           ^
sobel.cpp:15:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
class Circle {
      ^
sobel.cpp:21:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 0 were provided
    Circle(int x, int y, int r) {
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Could someone explain the error to me and how to fix it? As I see it, I have created a constructor that takes in 3 arguments. I'm not sure I understand why the error is saying I have provided 0 args.

Comment: @Miki hmm I see...that's weird.

Comment: @nz_21 It's not weird. Say you create std::vector<Circle> vec(2); How will std::vector instantiate those 2 objects of type Circle?

Comment: @Miki hmm...I'd rather exploit move semantics than have it copied over. I'm thinking of doing `return std::move(circles)` -- is that a good idea?

Comment: @nz_21, [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856344/when-should-stdmove-be-used-on-a-function-return-value)!

Comment: @nz_21 Please post a [mcve] (all C++ compiler errors should be able to be reproduced with very simple code).  If all of that OpenCV stuff is removed, and just simple vector manipulations are left in, the issue [cannot be duplicated](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8db72fe06417df9)

Comment: @Evg ah thanks for the link...but how do I guarantee that it will be moved and not copied?

Comment: @nz_21, the C++ standard gives you that guarantee. BTW, you can write `circles.emplace_back(x, y, r);`.

Comment: @Evg gotcha, thanks!

Comment: Note that `cv::Vector<Circle>` (your return type) is not the same as `std::vector<Circle>` (the type of `circles`) . You probably want to stick to one of them. (`cv::Vector` does not exist in more recent OpenCV versions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential part of your function is:

```
cv::Vector<Circle> foo() {
    std::vector <Circle> circles;
    return circles;
}
```

Here the type of `circles` is not the return type. A type conversion should take place. `cv::Vector<T>` has an implicit constructor

```
Vector(const std::vector<T>& vec, bool copyData = false)
```

that will be called to perform the conversion.

`std::vector<T>` itself does not require `T` to be default constructible, so the error happens inside `cv::Vector<T>::Vector`. Its `reserve()` member function, which is called during construction, has the following line:

```
newData = new T[newCapacity];
```

This line does require `T` to be default constructible. That's why you get the error and that's why `reserve()` is mentioned in the error log. To fix it, declare a defaulted default constructor:

```
class Circle {
public:
    Circle() = default;
    ...
};
```

Also note, that data from `circles` will not be copied into `Vector` unless you set `copyData` to `true`. The `return` statement should look like this:

```
return {circles, true};
```

or

```
return cv::Vector<Circle>(circles, true);
```

With

```
return circles;
```

`cv::Vector` will store a pointer to `&circles[0]`, that will become **invalid** after the local object `circles` is destroyed when the function returns.

A comment about `std::move`. You could try to do

```
return Vector<Circle>(std::move(circles), true);
```

This will not move anything. The shallow reason: the first constructor parameter has type `const std::vector<T>& vec`, you can't move from it, it's `const`. And the deep reason: to move from `std::vector` means to copy (or swap) an internal pointer to heap-allocated buffer. Implementation of `std::vector` is not specified, so there is no way to reuse its buffer in user-defined types like `cv::Vector`. `cv::Vector` allocates its own storage and copies elements into it, and you can't do better if you want `cv::Vector` to outlive `std::vector`.

The move semantics could have been useful if `cv::Vector` used `std::vector` internally to store its data and the constructor looked like this

```
Vector(std::vector<T> vec) : internal_vec(std::move(vec)) { }
```

To avoid unnecessary copies, you might want to use `cv::Vector<Circle> circles;` from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
sobel.cpp:15:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
class Circle {
```

The error message suggest the copy constructor is missing.
And this make sense because you are copying the Vector during return

Comment: this is one confusing language :( So, if I've got this right, the C++ standard guarantees it will be moved (not copied). And yet, I still have to create a copy constructor...

Comment: No, `Circle` does have an implicitly defined copy constructor.

Comment: It is because you are constructing a Vector from std::vector, and it is copying the elements. I am not familiar with Vector, but I guess you can try using `Vector<Circle> circles` instead of `std::vector<Circle>` for the loop

Comment: @Evg Agree. But Vector internally use Circle[] to store elements and this requires default constuctor