# Differences between return value optimization and `std::move`?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, move, rvo

What are the differences between return value optimization and `std::move`?
Do they depend on same internal implementation?

I understand that there are many places where must use `std::move`.

`std::move` and RVO both could achieve copy elision.For example, `T Func() {return T();}  T t=Func();`.I think i could not figure out which method the compiler really uses.

I am a novice in C++.I would be grateful for any hint on this question.

Comment: `std::move` is just a typecast, it has no relation to RVO

Comment: @Remy Lebeau `std::move` and RVO both could achieve copy elision.For example, `T Func() {return T();}  T t=Func();`.I think i could not figure out which method does the compiler really use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473753/c11-return-value-optimization-or-move

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856344/when-should-stdmove-be-used-on-a-function-return-value

Comment: RVO is a compiler optimization. The compiler is not smart, it is VERY smart and sees that it can reserve the area for return value on stack before reserving memory for the called function that returns value.
The returned value is therefore not destroyed when function goes out of scope and stack is decreased. The returned value is still there on stack.

move is more of a developer optimization and slower than RVO

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement

Comment: @ Per Ghosh I see.It makes clear to me how `RVO` is implemented.Then what about `std::move`?

Comment: @PerGhosh Note that since C++17, there is no longer RVO. There is guaranteed temporary deferred materialization, which is a bit different mechanism but basically with the same effect. And, it's not a compiler optimization, since it is prescribed by the Standard. (A difference is, for example, that for RVO you still need accessible copy/move constructor, while in C++17, there is no such need. This code: `std::atomic<int> f() { return std::atomic<int>{false}; } int main() { auto a = f(); }` compiles in C++17, but not in C++11/14.)

Comment: @sunshilong369 move is technique for you as a developer to optimize copy constructors for rvalues (values that is temporary and dies). You can create a copy constructor that know this and therefore "move" allocated data to the new object, not copy data. It's still a function call to the copy constructor. RVO has no call to functions, the objects it just there for use.

Comment: @PerGhosh  Thank you very much.What are major differences between `RVO` and `guaranteed temporary deferred materialization`?

Comment: @sunshilong369 Short answer - None. There is a small change that most developers never going to face. RVO do not use copy constructors. But if you create a class and specifically tells that copying isn't allowed. Then this object would generate an error when RVO kicked in but copying wasn't done.

Comment: @sunshilong369 Deferred temporary materialization needs neither copy nor move constructor. This is the case, for instance, of `std::atomic`, which I showed in the example in my previous comment. You cannot apply RVO with `std::atomic`. That's a major difference IMO, though classes without both copy/move constructors are relatively rare.

Comment: Yea, thank you.I have studied your example code and done some test.You make it clear to me.Thank you very much.BTW, what do you mean by "major difference IMO"?I could not find it in any dictionary.

Comment: @sunshilong369 You're welcome. [IMO = _in my opinion_](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=IMO) :).

Comment: @Daniel Langr  This code: `std::atomic<int> f() { return std::atomic<int>{false}; } int main() { auto a; a = f(); }` could not complie successfully in C++11 and C++17, since 
 copy constructor is still needed in this code.Could i think in this way?

Comment: @sunshilong369 1) `auto a;` — This is not legal in C++. 2) `a = f();` involves an assignment operator, not copy/move constructor.