# C++ Return a functor object as std::function

Tags: c++, functor, std-function

I have a factory method returning a `std::function`

```
class Builder {
public:
    function<void(Data&)> build();
}
```

and a functor object

```
class Processor {
protected:
    vector<int> content_;
public:
    void operator()(Data&) { 
         ....
    }
}
```

Now I want to return the functor in the factory method, and I write

```
function<void(Data&)> build() {
    Processor p;
    // Add items to p.content_

    function<void(Data&)> ret(p);

    return ret;
}
```

My question is: will `ret` maintain a copy of `p`? If so, when `p.content_` is large, will that become a burden? What will be a suggested way to implement this?

Comment: Use `void operator()(Data&&)` and `function<void(Data&)> ret(std::move(p));`. You'll need to implement move constructor (remember also rule of 5) for `Processor` class.

Comment: Hmm.. shouldn't the synthesised move ctor be enough? Rule of zero! You do need to return `std::move(ret)` though

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Moving from a local on return [is implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14856553/501250).

Comment: Your code is OK as written (assuming you don't mind `Processor` being copied). Indeed, `ret` makes a copy of `p`. You could have it moved instead with `function<void(Data&)> ret(std::move(p))`

Comment: Even better then!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I'm pretty sure that the return value optimization take care for `std::move(ret)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `std::function` hold and own its value. In fact, it requires callable object that are copiable so it can copy it when itself is copied.

Your function would be perfectly fine like this, and potentially faster:

```
function<void(Data&)> build() {
    Processor p;

    // fill items

    return p; // p moved into the returned std::function (since C++14)
}
```

However, if you copy the `std::function` around, the `Processor` object will be copied too, so the cost of copying the `std::function` depends on the type it contains (just as with any type erasure tools)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I also need to make changes to the local variable p (e.g., adding items to its content) so I need the local variable to be there.

Comment: @Harper I just added the last paragraph. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

The constructor that will be used is [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function):

```
template< class F >
function( F f );
```

You can see that the object will be copied. If you want to avoid this, you can move the callable:

```
function<void(Data&)> ret(std::move(p));
```

The constructor will then move `f` to the internal storage.

If your callable is small, it will be stored directly in the function object. If it is too large, the internal storage will be allocated dynamically. Either way, moving resulting function object should be no more complex than moving the original callable object (when stored directly in the function) or probably even cheaper (when stored dynamically).

Copying should be avoided when performance is important, as it might involve dynamic allocations even if your callable doesn't need them.