# For what reason do functions like std::sort() directly change the vector instead of return a value?

Tags: c++

I'm a novice with C++ and am wondering why `std::sort()` directly changes the array. I would naturally think that the `sort()` function should be like this:

```
anyVector = sort(anyVector.begin(), anyVector.end());
```

My question is: how `std::sort()` understands that it must change the order of the array content if you don't mention the array itself to be re-assigned?

I know that it could appear as a trivial question, but I didn't find any explanation (maybe because it's obvious for many).

Comment: [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) does a sort *in place*.

Comment: `std::sort()` sorts a range, provided by pair of iterators - the first for begin of the sequence, the second - one behind the last. Passing whole `vector` is just a variant of use.

Comment: I just needed the "in place" keyword thank you, now I read what means "pass by reference", I refreshed my old C notions with pointers, now it's clear the reason why sort use the reference and modify directly the value. Thank you very much @Eljay!

Comment: You're welcome.  :-)  "*I would naturally think...*" I also naturally think that way, as there are less surprises (referential transparency, immutability... which are more in the *functional programming* camp).  With *in place* mutability comes smaller memory footprint, which can be critical in many rather common situations, and provides some guarantees.  I just wish the name was `std::sort_in_place`.  Alas, that ship has sailed.

Answer (score 8):

Algorithms like `std::sort` don't know about the container. You pass iterators and the algorithm works on iterators. Hence `std::sort` has no way to return a vector.

The more profane reason is that you always have to choose between doing something in-place or creating a copy. When the algorithms does its job in-place, you are still free to make a copy:

```
std::vector<int> my_sort(const std::vector<int>& v) {
      auto result = v; // passing v by value and returning it defeats NRVO
      std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
      return result;
}
```

But the other way around is not possible. If the algorithm would make a copy, you cannot easily turn it into something that does not make a copy.

Comment: Your example could do with a tweak as NRVO cannot be exploited since `v` is a function parameter. It takes an unnecessary value copy.

Comment: @Bathsheba move into some local vector, then return that?

Comment: Or pass by const reference and create a copy inside

Comment: @Slava like that?

Comment: It's a really evil part of C++, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856344/when-should-stdmove-be-used-on-a-function-return-value

Comment: Yes the edit is how I would do it. Churlish of me not to have upvoted this before now, but here you go!

Comment: @Bathsheba I find the whole copy elision thing a bit annoying, because lots has changed, and I don't understand it fully.

Comment: That makes two of us.

Comment: I am afraid quite soon if not already nobody would fully understand what is going on there.

Comment: @Slava: I've taken the liberty of adding a useful comment. I'd allow a comment like that in my codebase.

Comment: @Bathsheba it wasnt immediately obvious to me, so thats the kind of comments I do use in code. Actually now I am curious and motivated to give it another try to understand, because naively I looks like a step back that I have to take a reference and cannot make the function signal to the caller that it makes a copy of the parameter, lets see how long that motivation will last