# Will initializing a const reference argument fom a default argument result in a dangling reference?

Tags: c++, lifetime

```
void foo(const std::string& s = "abc") {
    // ...
}

// ...

int main() {
    // ...
    foo();
    // ...
}
```

Will `s` in `foo` be dangling? I think because `std::string` will be constructed from default value `"abc"`, and then this will be a const reference do died temporary.

Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

`s` will not dangle in `foo`, but the temporary will live for the entirety of `foo`. There are a couple pieces that need to be understood to understand why this happens:

1. When you declare a default argument on the function, the default argument is inserted at the call site. The code you wrote behaves the same as the following code:

   ```
   void foo(const std::string& s) {
       // ...
   }

   // ...

   int main() {
       // ...
       foo("abc");
       // ...
   }
   ```

   So the `std::string` temporary is created at the call site.
2. When the temporary `std::string` is bound to the `const std::string& s`, the temporary is [lifetime extended](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary). It will live until the end of the complete expression, i.e. the semicolon at the end of `foo("abc");`.

Putting this together, we can see that `s` will not dangle, because it points to a temporary string which will live at least as long as `foo` will execute.

Answer (score 5):

The constructor for `std::string(const char*)` will be used to construct a temporary that will live for the whole lifetime of the function.

So there will be no problems.

Answer (score 3):

No, the lifetime of the temporary will be extended until the evaluation of the expression containing the call to `foo` ends. If `s` scape the function body then it will be a dangling reference.

in standardese [[class.temporary]/6.9](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6.9)

> A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call (8.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.

Comment: Note when you say `until the call to foo return` is not the same as `completion of the full-expression containing the call.`

Comment: Yes, you're right, I fixed the wording in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, the temporary will last until the end of the full expression containing the call to `foo`, we can see this from the draft C++ standard section [[class.temporary]p6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6) which says:

> The third context is when a reference is bound to a temporary object.<sup>38</sup>
>   The temporary object to which the reference is bound or the temporary object that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference if the glvalue to which the reference is bound was obtained through one of the following:
>
> ...

and then says further down:

> The exceptions to this lifetime rule are:
>   - A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call ([expr.call]) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.
>
> ....

which is the case we have here. For a clarification of `until the completion of the full-expression` see [What is the lifetime of a default argument temporary bound to a reference parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12554619/1708801).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not doing something like:

```
const char* temp;
void foo(const std::string& s = "abc") {
    temp = s.c_str();
}
```

Or anything like storing a reference to this const ref, you should be fine.